# How to modify a bash script after each run?

Tags: bash, awk

The following Script1.sh uses 1st (key) and 2nd columns (values) in every file and prints some output based on some code in other_scripts.sh. script2.sh simply runs both script1.sh and others_script.sh together.

Now, is it possible to extend the similar process to 1st and 3rd columns (output.n2) and repeat the process (output.nn)?

Note: I have around 20k columns. Every file has same exact number of columns.

$ cat file1

```
s   n1  n2  n3
s1  2   3   4
s2  3   4   5
s3  0   1   4
s4  9   8   7
```

$ cat file2

```
s   n1  n2  n3
s1  12  13  14
s2  13  14  15
s3  10  11  14
s4  19  18  17
```

$ cat file3

```
s   n1  n2  n3
s1  12  33  44
s2  13  43  54
s3  10  13  44
s4  19  83  74
```

$ cat filen

```
s   n1  n2  n3
s1  25  33  40
s2  35  43  50
s3  50  13  40
s4  95  83  70
```

script1.sh

```
awk '{print $1"\t"$2}' file1 | awk '{print $1"\t""file1""\t"$2}' >> r.1
awk '{print $1"\t"$2}' file2 | awk '{print $1"\t""file2""\t"$2}' >> r.1
awk '{print $1"\t"$2}' file3 | awk '{print $1"\t""file3""\t"$2}' >> r.1
awk '{print $1"\t"$2}' filen | awk '{print $1"\t""filen""\t"$2}' >> r.1
```

other_scripts.sh

```
grep file r.1 |awk '{print $1"\t"$2"\t"$3*100}' > output.n1
rm r.1
```

script2.sh

```
sh script1.sh
sh other_scripts.sh
```

output.n1

```
s1  file1   200
s2  file1   300
s3  file1   0
s4  file1   900
s1  file2   1200
s2  file2   1300
s3  file2   1000
s4  file2   1900
s1  file3   1200
s2  file3   1300
s3  file3   1000
s4  file3   1900
s1  filen   2500
s2  filen   3500
s3  filen   5000
s4  filen   9500
```

Comment: It's a little difficult to figure out what you're actually doing to your data. Could you please add some sample input and intended output to your question, so that we can test answers? It's almost certain that there's a better way to achieve what you're doing, whatever that is, and it would be better to solve the underlying problem than just help you achieve a less-than-optimal solution. (See: [XY Problem](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/XyProblem))

Comment: Write your variables to a separate data file, read from it in the script, and update that. Keep your code and data separate -- violating that rule leads to data loss, messy SCM content, security bugs (not running data as code is the most important step towards avoiding injection attacks), and other kinds of badness.

Comment: Also, in building code samples, please try to follow the guidelines at http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve -- code samples should be **minimal**, **complete** and **verifiable**. "Minimal" means it should be as small as possible while still demonstrating the problem; "complete" and "verifiable" mean that someone else should be able to copy/paste/run your code sample, and see the same error you're asking about; as it is, this is pseudocode, and not runnable.

Comment: Thanks for all your valuable comments. Now I edited the question. Hopefully it is clear now?

Comment: `other_scripts.sh` will copy in output only `file1`.  How do you define the strings like `"AA"` in script1.sh? Is there a relation between them and the number of the file?

Comment: they correspond to filenames. i modified it. please take a look.

Comment: It would be nice if input and output are consistent: I should be able to use the solution I am providing with your input and output...

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Try with this script. This reproduce exactly the output you required with the input you provided.

```
#!/bin/bash

NUMBER_OF_COLUMNS=3
NUMBER_OF_FILES=4    # Assuming the files are like file{n}


for coln in `seq 1 $NUMBER_OF_COLUMNS`; do
  for filen in `seq 1 $NUMBER_OF_FILES`; do
    awk -v n=$coln -v filen=$filen 'NR>1{printf"%s\tfile%i\t%s\n", $1, filen, $(1+n)*100}' file$filen >> output.$coln
  done
done
```

Copy it in a file, make it executable (`chmod +x <name of the file>`) and run the script (`./<name of the file>`) inside the directory containing all your files. Remember to put the right numbers as `NUMBER_OF_COLUMNS` and `NUMBER_OF_FILES`.

Comment: oh great thanks. but i need to run script2.sh each time it adds a number.

Comment: I think my post was confusing to many users and there were no examples of input (sorry). That is why they downvoted :( Now I edited the question. Hopefully it is clear now ?

Comment: Nope it is not. I get the following output for example output.n1  `s  file0   0`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/128178/discussion-between-user1883491-and-riccardo-petraglia).